# GHC does not see cabal package

Tags: haskell, opengl, module, cabal

This is my algorithm, which I have followed on my Mac to work with OpenGL.

```
$ cabal init sandbox
$ cabal install OpenGL
```

All done. They I import the module Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL and neither ghc or ghci see the module.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You do try this _in the sandbox_, right?

Comment: How are you invoking ghc & ghci?

Comment: import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main = do
  getArgsAndInitialize
  createWindow "Abdel"
  mainLoop

Comment: @UnseenElder Those appear to be the commands once you are in the GHCi repl.  What command do you use to start the GHCi repl?  cabal repl?  ghci? Something else?  The sandbox installs packages in its own directory and ghci needs to be told how to find those packages - if you don't then it will behave as though they aren't installed.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, when you install into a sandbox, you need to run ghc and ghci *in the sandbox* (i.e. via cabal commands like `cabal repl` or `cabal build`) to have access to the packages you have installed into a sandbox.

Comment: If you make this an answer, you could certainly add some full example, and perhaps also mention that a sandbox isn't _needed_ (in fact, I'd say sandboxes are obsolete now thanks to Cabal's Nix-style mode).